# How can I increase my python-code speed?

Tags: performance, python-2.7, loops

I have a dataframe, *df1*, that reports courses students have taken, where ID is the student’s id, COURSES is a list of courses taken by the student, and TYPE and MAJOR are student attributes.  The dataframe looks like this:

```
ID  COURSES                                          TYPE      MAJOR
1   ['Intr To Archaeology', 'Statics', 'Circuits I…] Freshman   EEEL
2   ['Signals & Systems I', ‘Instrumentation’…]      Transfer   EEEL
3   ['Keyboard Competence', 'Elementary …  ]         Freshman   EEEL
4   ['Cultural Anthro', 'Vector Analysis’ … ]        Freshma    EEEL
```

I created a new dataframe, *df2*, that reports a dissimilarity measure for each pair of students based on the courses they’ve taken. *df2* looks like this:

I created using the following script, but it runs very slowly (there are thousands of students).  Can someone suggest a more efficient way to create *df2*?

One major problem is that the script below calculates the distance between (student 1 and student 2) and (student 2 and student 1), which is redundant since the distances are the same. However, the condition I created to prevent this:

```
if (id1 >= id2):
    continue
```

doesn't work.

Entire script:

---

```
for id1, student1 in df.iterrows():
    for id2, student2 in df.iterrows():
        if (id1 >= id2):
            continue
        ID_1 = student1["ID"]
        ID_2 = student2["ID"]

        # courses as list strings
        s1 = student1["COURSES"]
        s2 = student2["COURSES"]
        try:
            # courses as sets
            courses1 = set(ast.literal_eval(s1))
            courses2 = set(ast.literal_eval(s2))
            distance =     float(len(courses1.symmetric_difference(courses2)))/(len(courses1) +     len(courses2))
        except:
            # Some strings seem to have a different format
            distance = -1

        ID_1_Transfer = 1 if student1["TYPE"] == "Transfer" else 0
        ID_2_Transfer = 1 if student2["TYPE"] == "Transfer" else 0


        df2=  df2.append({'ID_1': ID_1,'ID_2':     PIDM_2,'Distance': distance, 'ID_1_Transfer': ID_1_Transfer, 'ID_2_Transfer': ID_2_Transfer}, ignore_index=True)
```

Comment: Why are you doing `list(df.iterrows())` instead of `for id1, student1 in df.iterrows()` ?  df2 looks like ... what?  What do you mean your condition "doesn't work" ?

Comment: Thank you - I removed list.  Regarding the condition, I mean df2 still reports distances for student-pairs where the condition (id1 >= id2) is violated.  When, for instance, id1 < id2, the control is not returned to the start of the for loop, apparently.

Comment: You mention what df2 looks like, but nothing follows afterward.